# Slack integration: include user information in crash report

Tags: google-fabric

It would be great if messages with crash reports sent to Slack had data collected using `setUserIdentifier`, `setUserName`, and `setUserEmail`.

I suppose it just needs to be added after [line 84 here](https://github.com/crashlytics/crashlytics-services/blob/1621c9a25d313301fc649bfbf509997469e9c908/lib/services/slack.rb#L84).

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. We group specific crashes into issues and issues are sent to the third party integrations depending on your configurations within Fabric or Firebase. Since specific crashes for an individual would have different information then the issue, again specific versus aggregate, we don't include that information as it would likely only represent one of the many folks experiencing the crash.

Comment: I understand, an "issue" is an aggregation. What if an issue would have also additional info saying "<username> <id> <email> and <num> other users affected"? Where <username>/<id>/<email> would be the data from the most recent crash which has at least one of these fields. Could be just "<num> of users affected" if no crashes containing user info found. The best place for this is near the "View all sessions" button. This can also be sent to 3-party integrations. Would be super-fast to spot an affected anyone (or know if there is at least 1 name in a big pack before clicking through sessions).

Comment: It's a good idea! Not one that we plan on adding in right away, but will share this with the team.